# jQuery: Resizable Issue in FF - debug help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, jquery-ui, jquery-lint

Please try the following in Firefox (my version: 3.6.12).
This was working and now it's not.
IT does work in IE and it works in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/EWfWB/1/) from w/in FF - I'm thinking an addon may be affecting it.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <style type="text/css" media="all">
      .ui-resizable-e {right:0; background:#eee; z-index:1000;}
      .ui-resizable-w {left :0; background:#eee; z-index:1000;}
       #foo
           {
              background   : #fff;
              border       : 1px solid #ccc;
              margin       : 0 auto;
              padding      : 1em; 
              text-align   : left;
              width        : 75%;
           }

   </style>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){

         var foo = $('#foo');
         foo.resizable({
              animate       : true
            , animateEasing : 'swing' 
            , handles       : 'e,w'
            , resize        : function (event,ui){
                                 ui.position.left = ui.originalPosition.left;
                                 ui.size.width    = ( ui.size.width
                                                    - ui.originalSize.width )*2
                                                    + ui.originalSize.width;
                                 }
            });
      });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="foo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### To reproduce the error:

1. Grip one of the edges and resize the div (drag then release).
   Normally once this is done, the resize hook should be released, however for me it is not.
2. After unclicking the grip, I can click anywhere in the body (to the left/right of the grip) to resize the div.

I've included the full HTML (not lengthy) of my test page above.  All the css and script is linked to google's libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem exists in the [FireQuery v0.8](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) add-on to [Firebug v1.5.4](http://getfirebug.com/).

Specifically, I found turning `jQuery Lint` off in the console no longer produced the error above.

Please comment if you are able to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it in Firefox 3.6.12, all works fine - I can grip, move, when I release, it resizes. There's no "hanging release" issue that you mention.

Why don't you start it in safe mode (`firefox --safe-mode`) to test without addons?

Comment: I found the culprit, it was [fireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) add-on to Firebug.  Could you please install this and let me know for sure if that's the problem?  I have many add-ons installed and would like to know for sure.

Comment: I just installed FireBug 1.5.4 and FireQuery 0.8. All works fine until I turn on jQuery Lint. After that, it goes wacky. I would assume there are several ways to make it not work, but I think this is a speed issue - jQuery Lint was logging a lot, so it probably missed a few events here and there... Try and see if this is the same on your machine.

Comment: :) did you see my answer; you must have found it shortly after me

Comment: Well, you asked me to install and try - jQuery Lint looked as something that might be something to interfere... I saw your answer after I added the above comment, but I just realized it's you - thought it was somebody else... :)

Comment: Cheers, thx for the help.  BTW, for whatever reason my Windows box does not start FF w/o addons.  I think the Run command is `firefox -safe-mode`; additionally the safemode icon that is installed w/ FF doesn't work either.  It's not too much of a problem, except cases like these.

Comment: Hm... That's strange. Try running it with `firefox -ProfileManager` and make a dummy test profile. As you say, this is not important except in these cases, but don't know why it doesn't work...